# Dynamic image layout with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'd like to recreate the following image layout with HTML/CSS. Ideally, the aspect ratio of image 2 would automatically adjust to meet the aspect ratio of images 3 and 4.

I tried doing this with Flexbox, but I think I'd have to manually define flex amounts for each image, which is a pain. Any way to do this dynamically?

[image: layout]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `float` to set image next to each other.
For example (SCSS):

```
    .my-page{
        .layout-west{     <!-- For image 1 -->
            float: left;
            width: 186px;
        .layout-east{     <!-- Contain image 2, 3, 4, 5 -->
            float: left;
            width: 784px;

            .content-east{
                width: 784px; 
                margin: 0; 
                padding: 0; 

                .content-main{ <!-- Contain image 2, 3, 4 -->
                    float: left; 
                    margin: 0 10px 0 0; 
                    padding: 0px; 
                    width: 550px;
                .content-right{ <!-- Contain image 5 -->
                    float: left; 
                    width: 224px;
                }
```

In `.content-main`, you can use flex to for image 3 and 4

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. So, I'd still have to set the pixel width? There's no way to do it dynamically?

Comment: @underscore Maybe yes, if you want to responsive your image, you have to set the pixel width. Or otherwise, your image will take all the space